# arcpy and ArcGIS Pro: update Z values of a pointMZ geometry

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, geometry, cursor, z-value

I am trying to "reverse" the values of Z in a pointMZ geometry with `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`.
Anyway, I am not able to find a way to achieve this, although my script seems to work (no errors, printing the new Z values gives me the right output, but geometry always looks the same...). My try:

```
 import arcpy

 with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('my_feat.shp', "SHAPE@Z") as cursor:     
     for row in cursor:
         row[0] = -1 * row[0]
         print(row[0])
         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

My pointMZ geometry always looks the same (in terms of points displayed in my scene view), while I expected to set its Z values to their opposites and see them upside down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code **does** work - if you select a point, click the **Attribute** button under **EDIT**, and choose **Geometry**, you'll see your Z-value is negative.

What looks to be happening (or not happening) is the display doesn't immediately recognize that the underlying Z-values have changed. If you remove the layer and re-add it to your map the points will be "below the earth's surface"

Comment: Indeed. It's working. I just had the same file opened as in a map and a scene at the same time, so I probably wasn't able to see the edits. Thanks for the time!

Comment: All ```arcpy.mp``` API changes should force a refresh. A quick way to do this is: ```m = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT").listMaps()[0]``` to get a Map reference then ```m.defaultCamera.setExtent(m.defaultCamera.getExtent())``` to refresh the extent without changing it, which should refresh the entire interface.